# How to save my online game progress in case of corruption (Poki.com)

Tags: google-chrome

I play a few online games on poki.com, and all my progress data (like guns, upgrades, etc) are stored in my Chrome cache.

My question is simple: How do I save this cache if I want to switch computers or in the event that my Chrome profile gets screwed up (has happened many times before)?

I've tried looking through the forums and other places but I haven't found a working or applicable solution to my unique circumstance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about how browsers work, not gaming, and belongs on [su].

Comment: @pppery Fair point, I'll go ahead and ask my question there. Sorry for the trouble